# T-SQL: Check if an item in a small list is in a big list

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

If I have a master list of colour (nvarchar field) and I want to check if any item in a small colour list is in the master list  (nvarchar field).

e.g. Master List **'red | orange | green | blue | white'**

1. "**red** | **orange**" => true
2. "**white** | **green**" => true
3. "**red** | black" => true
4. "black | yellow" => false
5. "yellow" => false

What is the best way to tackle this in T-SQL?

Thank you.

Comment: *What is the best way to tackle this in T-SQL?* Store data in a relational format.

Comment: Sorry, I could not change the existing data format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple solution using:

1. [Table-Valued User-Defined Function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [XML nodes() method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) to convert the list into table.
2. [INTERSECT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) method to check if a value from the fist list is contained in the second

This is the function body:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'fn_ConvertListToNVarcharTable') AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF'))
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ConvertListToNVarcharTable]
END
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ConvertListToNVarcharTable] (@List nvarchar(max))
RETURNS @ResultRowset TABLE ([Value] NVARCHAR(250) PRIMARY KEY)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @XML xml = N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@List, '|', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>'

    INSERT INTO @ResultRowset ([Value])
    SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)')))
    FROM @xml.nodes('//r') Tbl(Col)

    RETURN
END

GO
```

And this is how a check can be made:

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT [Value] 
    FROM[fn_ConvertListToNVarcharTable]('red | orange')
    INTERSECT
    SELECT [Value] 
    FROM [fn_ConvertListToNVarcharTable]('red | orange | green | blue | white')
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'True'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'False'
END
```

Comment: +1 although i would work to check into a one-liner, so it can also be used on tables

Comment: @t-clausen.dk That's good point. In some cases, inline user functions can give better performance then multi-line ones.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a table valued function as:

```
create table tblMaster(color nvarchar(4000));
insert into tblMaster values ('red | orange | green | blue | white');
Go

-- Create a function to return data as rows of table.
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString](@String varchar(max), @Delimiter char(1))
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(max))
as
begin
    declare @idx int
    declare @slice varchar(max)

    select @idx = 1
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return

    while @idx!= 0
    begin
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)
        if @idx!=0
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)
        else
            set @slice = @String

        if(len(@slice)>0)
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)
        if len(@String) = 0 break
    end
return
end
Go
```

and then write a query as below to get the desired result:

```
Declare @color_mstr_list nvarchar(4000),@color_small_list nvarchar(4000);
select @color_mstr_list = color from tblMaster ;

select items into #temp from [dbo].[SplitString](@color_mstr_list,'|');

set @color_small_list = 'red | black';

with cte as
( 
select items from [dbo].[SplitString](@color_small_list,'|')
)
select case when COUNT(*) > 0 then 'True'
            else 'False'
            end  as Result   
from cte 
where exists ( select * from #temp T where T.items = cte.items )

drop table #temp;
```